# mongodump doesn't run in MacOS High Sierra

Tags: mongodb, macos

I follow the next guide to install MongoDB on my computer https://treehouse.github.io/installation-guides/mac/mongo-mac.html then I create a new database using mongod command. Everything was alright until when I tried to restore collections to the new database I created. When I run in terminal the command:

```
mongorestore --db database_name path_to_bson_file
```

Nothing happens, the terminal got stuck.
I have mongodb 3.6.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought that probably I could have and old version of mongodb so I run

```
brew install mongo
```

And then the terminal shows me the next message

```
Warning: mongodb 3.6.3 is already installed, it's just not linked.
You can use `brew link mongodb` to link this version.
```

So I run

```
brew link mongodb
brew link --overwrite mongodb
```

And then it works